# Showing that $\mathbb{C}$ is closed, open, perfect but not bounded - metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Consider the following subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}.$ The set of all complex numbers (i.e. $\mathbb{R}^{2}$).

I'm trying to show that this set is Closed, Open, Perfect but not Bounded.

**Closed:**

let us denote the set of all complex numbers by $E$. Then $E^{c} = \emptyset.$ It's vacuously true that $\emptyset$ is open. Hence $E$ is closed.

**Open:**

Similar to the above argument. The empty set is also Closed. Hence $E$ is open.

**Perfect:**

We need only, check that every point is a limit point. Let $z \in E.$ Then for $\epsilon > 0$ consider $B_{\epsilon}(z) = \{w: d(w,z) < \epsilon\}.$ I know that this is nonempty and therefore every point is a limit point, but I'm not really seeing how to explain why. (In my mind, I'm just thinking of drawing a small circle around the point $z$ then since we are dealing with Complex numbers it will of course contain another point!)

**Not Bounded:**

We need to show that for any $M \in \mathbb{R}$ and $z \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$, there is some $w \in \mathbb{C} \subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that $d(z,w) > M.$

I'm not too sure how to mathematically show it, but the fact it's the entire complex plane, it is clearly going to not be bounded! Is there a general strategy for proving bounded / not bounded properties of sets? This seems to be the part I struggle on most.

Comment: $\mathbb C\not\subset \mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @Surb Au contraire, $\mathbb{C}= \mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: @Surb $\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{R}^{2}$?

Comment: @ε-δ: $\Bbb C$ is not _equal_ to $\Bbb R^2$. For instance, $\Bbb C$ is a field, and $\Bbb R^2$ isn't.

Comment: @TonyK $\mathbb{C}$ is formally defined to be $\mathbb{R}^2$.  $\mathbb{C}$ is exactly what you get when you put a certain field structure on $\mathbb{R}^2$, but as sets they are formally equal.

Comment: @ε-δ: As I said, $\Bbb C$ is a field, i.e. a triple $\{S,+,\times\}$ containing a set $S$ (which can be $\Bbb R^2$ if you like) and two binary operations $+$ and $\times$. $\Bbb R^2$ is not.

Comment: @TonyK I just copied the question out of Rudin with my attempt at trying the problem.

Comment: But algebraic structure is not relevant here? Really, $\mathbb{C}= \mathbb{R}^2$ as sets and that's the only thing that matters here. This is analysis and no algebra.

Comment: @ε-δ: If as sets $\mathbb C=\mathbb R^2$ what would be a solution of $z^2=-1$ in $\mathbb R^2$ ?

Comment: $z^2 = -1$ uses FIELD STRUCTURE. If you consider these objects as sets there is no multiplication so that question makes no sense...

Comment: Well, I agree that as group $\mathbb C\cong \mathbb R^2$, but still, with out any other information, to say that $\mathbb R^2=\mathbb C$ is rather silly. @ε-δ

Comment: I know. I also write $\mathbb{C}$ if I want to stress the field structure, but as a set (and even as an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space) we have $\mathbb{C}= \mathbb{R}^2$ by definition of complex numbers. Rudin also uses this notation, as previously said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that a subset is bounded if it is contained in some open/closed ball. Clearly $\mathbb{C}$ is not contained in an open bal, so $\mathbb{C}$ is not bounded.

Comment: I agree that it is clear, but how would we mathematically explain it?

Comment: Show that $\mathbb{C}$ is not contained in an open ball. Surely this is trivial? If $B(z,r)$ is an open ball, then consider the complex number $z-r \notin B(z,r)$

Comment: That makes sense. I'm just not quite seeing the connection between the definition of not bounded I said and why we can just look at it being contained in some open/closed ball. I guess in the case of the open/closed ball we just take the radius as the value $M$ in the definition I gave?

Comment: What is your definition of bounded?

Comment: Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. A set $E \subseteq X$ is bounded if there is a real number $M$ and a point $q \in X$ such that $d(p,q) < M$ for all $p \in E$  (from Rudin)

Comment: Yes, this means that $E \subseteq B(q,M)$, so more loosely "$E$ is contained in an open ball", right?

Comment: Makes sense thanks! Wasn't viewing it like that before!